# Generate one random 5 digit number not present in a column of numbers

Tags: excel, random, vba

I have a list of 5 digit numbers. I need to randomly generate a 5 digit number that is not part of this list. I would like to achieve this on click of a button or simply by using a formula.
For example : If this is my column A in excel with 5 digit numbers,

```
11111  
11113  
11115
```

On click of a button I want to generate a unique 5 digit number which is not in this column.
I am using this function but it is only matching with the first cell. When I click on my button it gives me all numbers from 11110 to 11116 except 11111. I need it to check with full column and return me a unique value.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rw As Long
    For rw = 1 To 1
        Cells(rw, 2) = Int((11116 - 11110 + 1) * Rnd + 11110)
        Do Until Cells(rw, 2).Value <> Cells(rw, 1).Value
            Cells(rw, 2) = Int((11116 - 11110 + 1) * Rnd + 11110)
        Loop
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim rw As Long
For rw = 1 To 1
    Rnd_Num = Int((11116 - 11110 + 1) * Rnd + 11110)
    Do Until Columns(1).Find(Rnd_Num) Is Nothing
        Rnd_Num = Int((11116 - 11110 + 1) * Rnd + 11110)
    Loop
    Cells(rw, 2) = Rnd_Num
Next rw
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rw As Long
Dim start_, end_ As Integer
start = 11110
end_ = 11116
For rw = 1 To 1
    random_ = Int((end_ - start + 1) * Rnd + start)
    Do Until Columns(1).Find(random_) Is Nothing
        random_ = Int((end_ - start + 1) * Rnd + start)
    Loop
    Cells(rw, 2) = random_
Next rw
```